# Get URL with paths composed by N sub level with regexp

Tags: regex, google-analytics

i'm trying to get, starting from a list of URL paths, all the URLs with exactly 3 levels in the path using a **regexp** (I'm trying to isolate that for a filter in Google Analytics)

For example, from this list of URL Paths :

1. /lev1/lev2/
2. /lev1/
3. /lev1
4. /lev1/lev2/lev3
5. /lev1/lev2/lev3/

i want to isolate the paths nr 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) doesn't implement range expressions, otherwise I would have used `{3}` to simplify

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$
```

(With range expression: `^(/[^/]+){3}/?$`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just count the "/X"?

```
(?:\/.+?){,3}
```

With /lev1/lev2/lev3/, the regex matches /lev1/lev2/l